# using IF AND VLOOKUP and dates together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to use an IF AND function along with a vlookup to return prices from each supplier based on a given date

```
=IF(AND('Input Wheat'!$H$5:$H$1489=Summary!A7,'Input Wheat'!A5:A1207=Summary!C7,VLOOKUP(Summary!$B$4,'Input Wheat'!$F$5:$DE$1292,43,FALSE)))
```

Cell B4 contains the date.

Example of Sheet:
[image]

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but I think you're missing the closing paren on `AND()`:  `=IF(AND('Input Wheat'!$H$5:$H$1489=Summary!A7,'Input Wheat'!A5:A1207=Summary!C7),VLOOKUP(Summary!$B$4,'Input Wheat'!$F$5:$DE$1292,43,FALSE)))`?

Comment: @BruceWayne  it also looks like a potential array formula with those ranges in the AND function.  The other odd ball part (but admittedly not required) is what value is wanted it its false?  Since FALSE and 0 are not always the same thing I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Based (my understanding) of the conditions defined in your if().. try :

```
=INDEX('Input Wheat'!$F$5:$DE$1292,MATCH(1,('Input Wheat'!$H$5:$H$1489=Summary!A7)*('Input Wheat'!$A$5:$A$1489=Summary!C7)*(Summary!$B$4='Input Wheat'!$F$5:$DE$1292),0),43)
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

without sample data it is hard to test whether (Summary!$B$4='Input Wheat'!$F$5:$DE$1292) part works.. nevertheless.. have a try.. please share if it works.. (or not).. Hope it helps.